# How to calculate the sound volume for the left ear and right ear based on the object position & velocity, player position & forward vector? (3D sound)

Tags: game-mechanics, audio, sound, sound-effects

Please assume:

Minimum distance for 3D volume = 1.0;
Maximum distance for 3D volume = 100.0;

This is the declaration of the function:

An object can be a ball moving closer to the player.

```
void CalculateSoundVolume(Vec3 objectPosition, 
                          Vec3 objectVelocity, 
                          Vec3 userHead, 
                          Vec3 userFoward, 
                          float& leftEarVolume, 
                          float& rightEarVolume)  
{

}
```

Comment: I know that I can linearly or logarithmically lower the volume based on the player's position relative to the object. With that lowered volume in hand, how would I calculate the amount of lowered volume to be applied to the right ear and left ear?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395996/how-to-calculate-the-sound-volume-for-the-left-ear-and-right-ear-based-on-the-ob).

Comment: It's better to vote for the question in stack overflow rather than in game dev I believe.